# Confusing behavior from IDBKeyRange.includes

Tags: javascript, firefox, indexeddb

Firefox 47 is supposed to support `IDBKeyRange`'s `includes` method, but I'm having a hard time understanding why it's giving the results it is giving.

```
// These work as I'd expect to return false
console.log(IDBKeyRange.lowerBound(2).includes(1));
console.log(IDBKeyRange.lowerBound(4).includes(3));

// These do not behave as expected (I'd expect "true")
console.log(IDBKeyRange.lowerBound(1).includes(1)); // FF gives false
console.log(IDBKeyRange.lowerBound(3).includes(4)); // FF gives false
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does appear to be a bug in Firefox. I'll bring it to the developers' attention.

I've also filed a pull request to expand the tests used by browsers, and verified that the behavior is correct in Chrome:

https://github.com/w3c/web-platform-tests/pull/3216

...

Mozilla bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1281377

Comment: Thank you for your help and action on this. I've also just added an issue at https://github.com/w3c/web-platform-tests/issues/3218 asking for Node-based testing so that those of us working on Node-supporting polyfills can get the same benefits out of the box (without need for special scraping or config).